# Grouping elements based on common number available in JSONArray

Tags: java, json

I have to group the array elements (based on common number) and create a separate array for each group. For example

```
Array structure = [{Location, Date, Number}]

array = [{ 'LA','2017-12-01',1},
         { 'LA','2017-12-01',1},
         { 'NY','2017-12-01',2},
         { 'NY','2016-10-01',3},
         { 'LA','2017-12-01',1},
         { 'LA','2017-12-01',1},
         { 'LA','2017-12-01',1}]`
```

In the above array i have 6 ONES, 1 TWO and 1 THREE. so, totally i have 3 groups and i have to create 3 arrays for each group. Problem is am not able to create
separate array for each group and its not properly looping through.

Please find my below code that am trying.

```
List al=new ArrayList();
for(int i=0;i<lineItemsArray.length();i++)
    {
        JSONObject lineObj1 = lineArr.getJSONObject(i);
        for(int j=0;j<lineItemsArray.length();j++)
        {
            JSONObject  lineObj2 = lineArr.getJSONObject(j);
            if(lineObj1.getString("number")
                    .equalsIgnoreCase(lineObj2.getString("number")))
                {
                    al.add(lineObj2.getString("number"));
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Arrays.stream` to transform you array into a stream and group it:

```
Map<Object, List<JSONObject>> numberMap = Arrays.stream(lineItemsArray).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(item -> item.get("number")));
```

Answer (score -1):

Finally, i got the way to group common JSONArray elements.

```
Map<Object, List<JSONObject>> numberMap = IntStream.range(0, lineItemsArray.length())
            .mapToObj(index -> (JSONObject) lineItemsArray.get(index))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(item -> item.get("number")));
```

Comment: see my answer for a simpler solution: you don't need at all to bother with array's index.